# How to get Window's logged in User Name and Password using ASP.NET WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net, api, web

I am working on a Intranet application where i am calling a SAP service from a ASP.NET WEB API, Currently it is working fine with a HttpBasicAuthentication with a predefined user name and password. But now the requirement is to get the logged in windows user's user name and password through ASP.NET WEB API and pass it to the SAP service for authentication? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Let me know if the solution helped you or if you need any further help on this

Answer (score 0):

1) HttpBasicAuthentication won't apply in this case.

2) Use identity impersonate via the web.config tag (ref [Identity Impersonate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx)) to have the current user's identity taken up in api. However this will **only** work for Intranet based applications and not over internet. For Internet based, you will need to have Kerberos bridge (somewhat complicated) concept implemented.

3) In you app.start method, you need to set the current principal to windows principal.

Then you can have the user detail available..

Please note that you **will not** have the user's password available as OS protects that very very securely. You can get the user's Kerberos token though which your target system can auth against the AD being used.